# Mouse scroll works only couple seconds after restart

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, macos

It seems like my mouse scroll works only for a short period of time after restart. I use Bluetooth mouse Logitech MX Master with installed it’s Logitech options.

I tried to reinstall the Logitech Options, reset NVRAM and PRAM, forgetting device and reconnecting it.

There is no problem with the mouse itself (mechanically).

Thanks.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I ask if you've tried using the Logitech MX Master connected via a USB cable to see how it behaves? If so, does it work fine? If not, can you try that for a while to determine if it behaves properly or not?

Comment: Hello, same problem, tried to restart it when connected via USB, worked couple seconds, then it feels like some driver loaded up and scroll wheel stopped working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. Apparently deleting the app Logitech Options the regular way isn't enough. I did find the remaining file Logitech Uninstaller, when I got rid of it, the mouse started scrolling properly. It seems like Logi has some issues with the newest Logitech Options and it ruins scrolling drivers with Mojave. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still encountering the same issue in 2022 with a m590 on macOS Big Sur version 11.4.

**Uninstalling** through the uninstaller and simply **reinstalling** Logi Options fixes the scroll wheel problem.

I didn't have any problems other than occasionally getting disconnected for the past year and a half.